# Perl regex to match up to but not including optional end-token

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to efficiently match lines up to but not including an optional end-token.

```
/(.*)(?:$tok)?/
```

doesn't work. The end-token is optional, hence the final ?, but then the first group
greedily captures it.

```
/(.*?)(?:$tok)?/
```

also doesn't work: the first group matches a zero-length string

The best I can do so far is

```
my $tok = 'end';
while (<>) {
    my ($line) = /
       (?|             # 'branch reset'
           (.*)$tok    # either a line terminated with the end token
         |             # or
           (.*)        # the whole line
       )               # end branch reset group
    /x;
    print $line, "\n";
}
```

This works, but strikes me as inefficient. The regex engine has to parse the line twice, which is what I was trying to avoid.

I'm aware the problem as stated would be better solved with index():

```
my $i = index($_, $end);
$line = $i < 0 ? $_ : substr $_, 0, $i;
```

but I need to do other processing of the line making a regex desirable - and in any event, I see this as a learning opportunity ;-)

Comment: Please provide an example of a line you are trying to match, and the output you expect in the capture groups after applying the regex.

Comment: For the above as stated, with the end-token being the text 'end', the three lines 'depend', 'dependent', and 'minnow' would produce 'dep', 'dep', and 'minnow'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the following example. Here it is looking for the word `great` at the end of the matching or the end of line(`$`).

```
my $str = 'alexander the great alex';
if ($str =~ m/(.*?)(?=great|$)/i) {
    print "$1";
}
```

You can replace your `$token` with `great` from above example.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed does work. I swear I read that forward assertion stuff in perlre until I was crosseyed, and couldn't make it work!

Comment: I've tested the performance of my original regex and the one you've suggested. The branch reset version takes about 1/2 the time of the positive look-ahead assertion version, which is definitely not what I expected. But at least I now know more about assertions :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
/^(.*?)(?:(?:\b$tok)?$)/gm
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/tK7zS0)

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't quite do what I need: I should have specified that the input lines are not necessarily broken into words and the end-token can be any arbitrary sequence of characters and can appear more or less anywhere. The link to the regex tester is useful, but I can usually get mine to work. This one obviously had me defeated, though.